# Can kie server handle json to send the planning probleme

Tags: optaplanner

I'm using optaplanner kie workbench and kie server.  How can I use json instead of XML to send planning probleme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just need to use `Content-Type: application/json` header in your request. If you want to learn more about this topic, check out the [documentation](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.24.0.Final/optaplanner-wb-es-docs/html_single/#kie-server-rest-api-con_kie-apis).